# Delete rows in an access linked table from VB

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

Is it possible to delete rows in an access linked table(linked to an oracle table)
from a visual basic program ? If yes what is the VB code to perfom this action ?

I tried the code below but i have an error saying cannot delete rows ( i have already checked the user rights, in VB its ReadWrite):

VB Code:

```
Dim connectString As String

connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\accessDB.mdb;"

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.Open connectString

strSQL = "delete * from linked_table_to_delete ;"

c.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: You tagged it as vb.net but wrote VBA code.  Which are you actually using?

Comment: You don't need an asterisk. Use DELETE FROM linked_table_to_delete.

Comment: i am using Visual Basic 6. sorry for the mistaken tag

Comment: If you open the database in Access and then open the linked table can you delete rows from there?

Comment: I tried without the asterisk and i still have the error "2147467259" saying "impossible to delete in specified tables" !

Comment: Mr Thompson, when trying to delete from access the option delete row is greyed out, then cannot delete from Access

Comment: By the way use WHERE otherwise you will delete everything! Like `DELETE FROM linked_table_to_delete WHERE condition here`. Also in MS Access don't open it while running your program in VB6. Close your MS Access before executing your program in VB.

Comment: Thank you Edper, in fact i want to delete everything because after i will reload the table from scratch, that why i didn't put any condition

Comment: I tried also with the MS Access cloed and still have the same error

Comment: Is it possible that your MS Access is read-only? Try, to right-lick then Properties and then uncheck read-only. Also you should not put your MS Access in the root directory c:\  - move it in a folder instead say on test folder, that it, would become c:\test\accessDB.mdb

Comment: If you can't delete rows from within Access itself then you won't be able to delete rows from your VB6 app either. Try deleting and re-creating the table link, making sure to specify the primary key column(s) if prompted for them.

Comment: But when i created another linked table from the original one (copy /paste), i am able to drop it but not delete it! i have tested it with the new linled table to avoid loosing my original table

Comment: In Access, right-click the linked table and choose "Design View". Do you see the primary key icon (little picture of a gold coloured key) immediately to the left of at least one of the field names?

Comment: No there no key. there is no primary key that have been set for the table